# Get current day + 1 in GMT

Tags: javascript, date, cookies

I am able to get the current date, but I don't know how to get the current date + 1 day (in GMT)

```
var now = new Date();
var newexp = (now + 3);
var show = newexp.getGMTString();

alert(show);
```

What I'm really trying to do is set a cookie to expire in 1 day.

```
function SetCookie(name, value, exp) {
 var now = new Date();
 var newexp = (now + exp); // exp being # of days before expiration
 document.cookie= name + "=" + value+ "; expires=" + newexp.getGMTString() + ";"
}

SetCookie('name', 'john', '3');
```

Obviously, this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function SetCookie(name, value, exp) {
var now = new Date();
now.setTime(now.getTime()+(exp*24*60*60*1000));
document.cookie= name + "=" + value+ "; expires=" + now.toGMTString() + ";"
}

SetCookie('name', 'john', '3');
```

edited it to take the exp as the factor, it is the no. of days.

Comment: Where does this factor in the `exp`? (not working for me btw)

Comment: updated the code to take into account the no. of days passed as exp.

Comment: It's not setting the cookie at all :(

Comment: sorry, updated the code, the getGMTString i copied from your code is wrong. (verified, above code works fine now).

Comment: function SetCookie(name, value, exp) {
var now = new Date();
now.setTime(now.getTime()+(exp*24*60*60*1000));
var domain = document.domain;
document.cookie= name + "=" + value+ "; expires=" + now.toGMTString() + "; domain= "+domain+"; path=/;"
}

SetCookie('name', 'john', '3');

Comment: Note that with the variable named like that, after the `setTime` call it's a bit of a lie...

Comment: @JonSkeet: can you please explain, I am really sorry, but I have always used it as this. It would be great if I can learn something :)

Comment: @Neo: After you've called `now.setTime()`, the value of the `now` variable is really "some days from now" isn't it? See my answer for some alternative choices which never end up with a "lying" variable name.

Comment: Once you modify the time contained in `now`, it's no longer semantically representative of *`now`*.

Comment: so it is the variable name which is not semantically correct. I thought the expiry would be set to something else. I preferred to use the same variable name so that it is easy for @JohnRobinson to understand. No comments on though which ans is great, we all know none is wrong.

Comment: @JonSkeet might deem it differently, but variable naming that's imprecise and thumb-in-the-wind-drawn accurate isn't wrong, but as a practice it's inaccuracy could lead to errors that are hard to spot. Bad habit to get into.

Comment: @Neo: Yes, the *result* is correct, but the code is misleading. Using the same variable to mean two different things, only one of which is in line with its name, is a bad idea IMO. Heck, even the OP's original code uses `now` and `newexp`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: completely agree with you.

Answer (score 5):

The Javascript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/) object lets you manipulate the date it stores in it really easily.

All you need to do to get a Date object for tomorrow is...

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
```

Comment: The Date object handles that for you - take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) .

Comment: I did, and the documentation for `setDate` specified "Sets the day of the month (1-31) for a specified date according to local time." - so what happens if you give it 32?

Comment: Ah... just followed the link to `setDate` which clarifies what it does if the parameter *isn't* in that range. Somewhat misleading doc summary there, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of thinking about it is to get back to the fundamental "milliseconds since the epoch" representation:

```
var date = new Date()
date.setTime(date.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

Or with two separate variables:

```
var now = new Date()
var expiry = new Date(now.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

Or inlining it:

```
var expiry = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

Note that this will give you the date *24 hours after now*. That's *not* the same time as "the same local time tomorrow" which could be 23 or 25 hours (or even not exist if it's December in Samoa in 2011). Personally I prefer the nice stable approach of "a fixed length of time" but YMMV.

Obviously to make the expiry a different number of days, just multiply the 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 constant (which is the number of milliseconds in a day) by the number of days you want.

Comment: You could do `new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`. (Forgot the closing parens...)

Comment: @JaredFarrish: True. Still, someone else may find it useful. I wanted to focus on the time-based aspect of the question - the cookie part is pretty irrelevant, IMO :)

Comment: That was meant in a "isn't it sad?" kinda way. The question title is a little misleading (should be "Set cookie expiry to one day ahead"); I prefer the explanation, just kinda sad, y'know?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: :shrugs Yup. Still, everyone gets what they want this way, in the end. SO is great like that, regardless of which answer is accepted :)